# Fail safe delivery of messages to n queues(sqs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-sqs

Problem Statement =>

A message in an sqs/sns(queue) would be consumed by a consumer.

The consumer's few roles ->

1. Filter whether the message should be multiplexed .
2. Based on the message data decide which downstream queues the message needs to be pushed to.
3. The message is then pushed to n queues.

Now the problem which arises is that there may be some **catastrophe** when the message were being pushed to the *downstream queues*. Here let's assume the message needs to be pushed to **5 queues**, but because of **some failure** only **3 queues** got the message and the remaining **2 queues** did not get the message.

Now after recovery from the failure, our consumer would like to a send/multiplex message by consuming  the initial message again. Now this time only the **2 remaining downstream queues** should receive the messages and not the **previous 3 downstream queues** where the message was already delivered before the failure.
*Our requirement is that messages be delivered to each downstream queue only once or never.*

**How do we achieve this ?**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an **Amazon SNS Topic** to 'multiplex' the messages.

The architecture would be:

- Your downstream queues subscribe to an **Amazon SNS Topic**
- Your existing consumer performs its logic to determine how the message should be processed. It then sends the message to the Amazon SNS Topic, with **attributes** that identifies the message type.
- Amazon SNS then uses **subscription filter policies** to forward to the message to selected Amazon SQS subscribers based on those policies

From [Amazon SNS subscription filter policies - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html):

> A subscription filter policy allows you to specify **attribute names** and assign a list of values to each attribute name. When Amazon SNS evaluates message attributes against the subscription filter policy, it ignores message attributes that aren't specified in the policy.

With this architecture, Amazon SNS is responsible for forwarding the messages to the downstream Amazon SQS queues. Amazon SNS has in-built [message delivery retries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html) that will **retry, backoff and then keep trying to send** the message for 23 days.